# Postgres role trouble: Cannot limit access to a table

Tags: postgresql

I have created a role "rysmier" that will give permission to SELECT only to a single view in a database.

```
CREATE ROLE rysmier WITH 
    NOSUPERUSER
    NOCREATEDB
    NOCREATEROLE
    NOINHERIT
    LOGIN
    NOREPLICATION
    NOBYPASSRLS
    CONNECTION LIMIT -1;
```

Then I allowed the view to be accessed by this role.

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='v_finwell';

grantee |privilege_type|
--------+--------------+
postgres|INSERT        |
postgres|SELECT        |
postgres|UPDATE        |
postgres|DELETE        |
postgres|TRUNCATE      |
postgres|REFERENCES    |
postgres|TRIGGER       |
```

It looks as if only the user postgres has rights in that table.

However, I then do:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.v_finwell TO rysmier;
```

Then checking the rights again gives me:

```
grantee |privilege_type|
--------+--------------+
postgres|INSERT        |
postgres|SELECT        |
postgres|UPDATE        |
postgres|DELETE        |
postgres|TRUNCATE      |
postgres|REFERENCES    |
postgres|TRIGGER       |
rysmier |SELECT        |
```

So now rysmier has select rights.

but:

```
SELECT x.* FROM public.v_finwell x
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation v_finwell
```

Why? I've spent a lot of time on this and read so many posts, but nothing seems to be pointing me in the right direction to figure this out.

UPDATE: It may be that all changes where not committed, since now I do have access to the view.  However, I can still see the structure of the table on which the view is based, despite having no SELECT or other rights on that table.

```
# SELECT grantee, privilege_type FROM information_schema.role_table_grants WHERE table_name='newtable';
 grantee  | privilege_type 
----------+----------------
 postgres | INSERT
 postgres | SELECT
 postgres | UPDATE
 postgres | DELETE
 postgres | TRUNCATE
 postgres | REFERENCES
 postgres | TRIGGER
```

However, "rysmier" has access to more than only this view.
Logged in as rysmier:

```
data_replication=> \d newtable;
                                            Table "public.newtable"
           Column            |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
-----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id                          | integer               |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 Replication rule            | character varying(10) |           |          | 
 transaction_history_id      | integer               |           |          | 
 replication rule account id | integer               |           |          | 
 compound transaction id     | integer               |           |          | 
 tx_reference                | character varying     |           |          | 
 value date                  | date                  |           |          | 
 amount                      | money                 |           |          | 
 sign                        | character(2)          |           |          | 
 account_balance             | money                 |           |          | 
 event_type                  | character varying     |           |          | 
 account_id                  | integer               |           |          |
```

How can I prevent this, ie I only want this role to be able to "see" the data in v_finwell?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  What version are you using?

Comment: running pgsql 10